# xampp change location of htdocs

Tags: windows, xampp, location, htdocs

Installed **xampp-windows-x64-7.4.6-0-VC15** on a reinstalled Windows 10.
Used the default install folder : *C:\xampp*

I need to point to a different **htdocs** folder. Instead of **C:\xampp\htdocs** I need to have my site located in **C:\Users\gadib\Dropbox\GADI\xampp\htdocs**.

Searched the entire internet (YES, I did!) and all relevant entries suggest that I need to edit 2 lines in C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf :

```
Define SRVROOT "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
```

and replace **C:/xampp/htdocs** with the path to the desired folder.

BUT... the 2 lines I have in this file are :

```
Define SRVROOT "C:/xampp/apache"
ServerRoot "C:/xampp/apache"
```

Note that these end with **apache** and not with **htdocs** !!!

I tried anyway :

```
Define SRVROOT "C:\Users\gadib\Dropbox\GADI\xampp\htdocs"
ServerRoot "C:\Users\gadib\Dropbox\GADI\xampp\htdocs"
```

and when starting Apache (via the xampp control panel) it failed with :

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.   etc...
```

Any idea/hint/suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:
Sorry if I get you wrong... But if you are talking about the ServerRoot it is very normal to be "C:/xampp/apache" since it is for everyone like that. ServerRoot is the top of the directory tree under which the server's configuration, error, and log files are kept... However the DOCUMENTROOT must be C:/xampp/htdocs For example: DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs" I hope this will help you out :)

Comment: Yes, that crossed my mind too. I will do that if I don't get an answer to my question, which is : why do I have in httpd.conf "C:/xampp/apache" instead of "C:/xampp/htdocs" like all others. What did I do wrong? (Was it something I said...?)

Comment: Sorry if I get you wrong... But if you are talking about the ServerRoot is is very normal to be "C:/xampp/apache" since it is for everyone like that. ServerRoot is the top of the directory tree under which the server's configuration, error, and log files are kept...
However the DOCUMENTROOT must be C:/xampp/htdocs 
For example: DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
I hope this will help you out :)

Comment: Ooooo... I am so embarrassed. You are right : I was editing the SERVERROOT instead of the DOCUMENTROOT.   My bad. Once I edited the proper parameters - everything works fine. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it as one. Thank you so much for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: @gadi I did edit the answer I'm happy that I could help you :)

Comment: why does D:/server/htdocs work fine but D:/server doesn't ??